# Proving $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1}$ has no limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I want to prove the sequence
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n\cdot n}{n+1}$$
has no limit as $\,n\to+\infty$.

I tried to work with inequalities to get that $\,|a_n-L|\geqslant\varepsilon\,$ and the way I tried to solve it was to divide into cases:
$\,L\geqslant0\,$ or $\,L<0\,.$
When I did the case with $\,L\geqslant0\,,\,$ I chose an even $\,n\,$ and I found there is $\,\varepsilon=L\,$ for which this is true, but I don't know if I am allowed to represent $\,\varepsilon\,$ with $\,L\,$ or should I represent it as a number.
And I would also be glad if someone could show me the way to solve this because my prof hasn't shown us this although he gave us to do that.

Comment: you can check that when n is even and n is odd, two subsequences converge to different limits

Comment: but can I represent epsilon with L?

Comment: @miiky123, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score 9):

This is how to do it using the definition of limits.

We say that $a_n$ converges (to $L$) iff
$$\exists L \in \mathbb{R} \; \forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N} \; \forall n\geq n_0 : |a_n - L| < \varepsilon.$$
Hence, we say that $a_n$ does **not** converge iff
$$\forall L\in\mathbb{R}\; \exists \varepsilon > 0 \; \forall n_0\in\mathbb{N} \; \exists n\geq n_0 : |a_n - L| \geq \varepsilon,$$
or in other words, you want to **find** an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|a_n - L| \geq \varepsilon$ is satisfied for infinitely many $n$.

Let $L\in\mathbb{R}$ be given and take $\varepsilon = |L|$ (or, if $L=0$, set $\varepsilon = 1/2$). Let moreover $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ be given.

**Case 1:** $L > 0$. Define $n = 2n_0 + 1 > n_0$. Then $(-1)^n = -1$ and
$$|a_n - L| = L -\frac{-(2n_0 + 1)}{2n_0 + 2} = L + \frac{2n_0 + 1}{2n_0 + 2} > L = \varepsilon.$$
**Case 2:** $L < 0$. Define $n = 2n_0 > n_0$. Then $(-1)^n = 1$ and
$$|a_n - L| = \frac{2n_0}{2n_0 + 1} - L > -L = \varepsilon.$$
**Edit: Case 3:** $L=0$. Define $n=n_0+1$. Then
$$|a_n - L| = \frac{n}{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{2} = \varepsilon,$$
where $\frac{n}{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\geq 1$ is an easily verified inequality.

Since this covers both cases, we are done.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it!

Comment: Thank you very match

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to prove this is to show that subsequence of even indices converges to 1 ($x_{2n}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}$) and subsequence of odd indices converges to −1 ($x_{2n-1}=-\frac{2n-1}{2n}$). This is in contrary with the theorem: ***If a sequence has a limit x, then all subsequences of that sequence have the same limit x***.

---

***EDIT:***
It can be easily derived from the previously said that there exists a limit of a sequence $y_n=(-1)^nx_n$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=0$. It is also clear that $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n=0$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

When dealing with oscillating sequences, the triangle inequality is handy.

That is, for any $~a_r,a_s,L \in \Bbb{R},~$

$$|a_r - a_s| \leq |a_r - L| + |L - a_s|. \tag1 $$

Therefore, when constructing an $~\epsilon,N~$ proof, if you can specify a specific value for $~\epsilon~$ such that no matter how far in the sequence that you go, you will always be able to find $~a_r, a_s,~$ beyond that point in the sequence such that $~|a_r - a_s| > 2\epsilon,~$ then you are done.

The reason is that no matter what $~L~$ is chosen, it will  have to obey the inequality in (1) above.  So, if the LHS of (1) above is $~> 2\epsilon,~$ it will be impossible for both terms on the RHS of (1) above to be $~\leq \epsilon.$

In the present case, with
$~\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{n+1} = 1,~$ 
and with the elements $~a_n~$ oscillating between positive and negative, 
simply specify that (for example) $~\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}.$

If you can show that when $~\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2},~$ that it is impossible for there to exist any value $~L,~$ such that beyond a certain point $~a_N~$ in the sequence, all of the following elements satisfy $~|a_n - L| \leq \epsilon,~$
then you are done.

Using the idea in (1) above, the problem reduces to showing that for any $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ there will always exist $~r,s > N,~$ such that $~|a_r - a_s| > 2\epsilon = 2 \times \dfrac{1}{2} = 1.$

Given the oscillating nature of the sequence, and given any value $~N,~$ choose any $~r,s > N,~$ such that $~r~$ is odd and $~s~$ is even.

Then, you will have that

$$a_r < \frac{-1}{2}, ~a_s > \frac{1}{2} \implies |a_r - a_s | > 1 = 2\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

The $(-1)^n$ in the numerator indicates that $a_n$ is positive if $n$ is even and negative if $n$ is odd. Therefore, there is only one number this sequence may converge to. It suffices to show that $\frac{n}{n+1}$ does or does not converge to that number.

Comment: The case of $f(n) + (-1)^n g(n)$ would necessarily fail the above analysis unless $f$ and $g$ were treated separately.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $c_n\to c\neq 0.$ Then the sequence $a_n=b_nc_n$ is convergent iff $b_n$ is convergent, as $b_n=a_n/c_n.$ Apply this to $c_n=n/(n+1)\to 1$ and $b_n=(-1)^n.$ Since $b_n$ is divergent, so is $a_n.$

Another approach: assume the sequence $b_n-a_n$ is convergent.Then $a_n$ is divergent iff $b_n$ is divergent. We can apply that to $a_n=(-1)^n{n\over n+1}$ and $b_n=(-1)^n,$ as $b_n-a_n=(-1)^n{1\over n+1}\to 0.$

Comment: $b_n = (-1)^n$, $c_n = (-1)^n$ is a case where $a_n$ converges to 1 and neither $b_n$ nor $c_n$ converge.

Comment: @user121330 that's not really relevant in this argument, though, since we are starting with the assumption that $c_n$ does converge, and to a nonzero number.

Comment: @MW I'm looking for that assumption in the text above ...

Comment: @user121330 very first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|a_{n}-a_{n-1}\right|=\left|(-1)^n \left( \frac {n(n+2)+(n-1)(n+1)}{n(n+1)} \right)\right|$$
$$=\frac{2n^2+2n-1}{n(n+1)}$$
$$2-\frac 1 {n(n+1)}$$

If $n>0$, we are subtracting at most $\frac 1 2$, so the difference is greater than $1$.

Therefore, this is not a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), and thus does not converge

Comment: ${1\over 2}\le |a_n|<1,$ hence $|a_n-a_{n-1}|<2.$ However $|a_n-a_{n-1}|>1.$

Comment: The idea of showing the sequence is not Cauchy is a good addition, but the mishandled algebra is bad. You should correct it. And note that you do not get to just drop the sign unless you take the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using [neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) and the fact that for all convergent sequences $\vec{p}$ with limit $x$, it holds for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, that finitely many elements fall outside of $U$.

For the purposes of this sequence, I'll assume that $a$ starts at $a_0$ which is $0$.

I'll show that $\vec{a}$ can't approach anything by pointing out explicit neighborhoods of every real number with infinitely many points outside of them.

I claim that $\vec{a}$ does not approach $0$. I choose as my neighborhood the open interval $(-\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{10})$. Aside from $a_0$, all other elements of the sequence are outside of this set.

Let $w$ be a positive number. There are infinitely many elements of $\vec{a}$ outside of $(w/2, 2w)$ because the elements associated with positive odd indices are negative.

Let $w$ be a negative number. There are likewise infinitely many elements of $\vec{a}$ outside of $(2w, w/2)$ because the elements associated with positive even indices are positive.

Thus $\vec{a}$ does not converge.